# Export specific range into an HTML

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to export the range **("A1:C10")** from sheet `Sheet1` as **HTML** and save it in the same directory as the current workbook. I also want to keep the source formatting.

I am using the following code, but I get errors and I cannot define the destination folder as the same folder where the current workbook resides.

```
Sub Export()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
Filename:=file1, _
sheet:="Sheet1", _
Source:=rng, _
HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish

End Sub
```

I also tried this:

```
Sub Export()
Dim rng As Range


Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
fileName:="C:\exported.xlsx", _
Sheet:="Sheet1", _
Source:=rng, _
HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you set the value of file1 in the code `Filename:=file1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Source:=` expects a string value with a address of a range, not a `Range` object.

The path of the Workbook which contains the macro can be gotten with `ThisWorkbook.Path`.

```
Sub Export()
 Dim rng As Range

 file1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.html"

 Set rng = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:C10")

 ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
 SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
 Filename:=file1, _
 Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, _
 Source:=rng.Address, _
 HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish

End Sub
```