# Export from Excel to html

Tags: html, excel, html-table

I need to export a Excel table to a html table, but I don't know how can I achieve that.

I can see I can export it into CSV and etc, but that is not a good method, any better idea to achieve that?

Comment: $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                  "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
             }
    } );
} );

Comment: @AshwinGolani This is supposed to be a solution for Excel. There is not indication that the OP downloaded and installed TableTools (nor if he has any knowledge on how to make use of it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export specific range into an HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562942/export-specific-range-into-an-html)

Comment: what do you want to do with the data once converted from excel to html?