# In Excel how do you get the html representation of a selection stored into a variable?

Tags: vba

I have a bunch of cells that I won't to get the html representation of.

From the post [Export specific range into an HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562942/export-specific-range-into-an-html) I use the answer to save an html representation to a file, but is there a way to output it to a variable instead?

My final use of this html does not except classes in the html so I need to search and replace text within the output before I can use it.

Is there a way to change the output of the following code from a file to a variable?

```
Sub Export()
 Dim rng As Range

 file1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.html"

 Set rng = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:C10")

 ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
 SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
 Filename:=file1, _
 Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, _
 Source:=rng.Address, _
 HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you use `=FilterXML(...)`?

Comment: How do I get the html text into a variable for me to use FilterXML? Without first exporting to a file and then loading the text of that file into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The content of your sheet's range is already stored in the rng object variable, hence, all of its information is there, it will prevail as long as you like in the code, why would you add another variable to it?

Comment: Publishing creates an htm file with styles that make the webpage look identical to the worksheet. The string representation of this webpage is what I want stored in the variable not the range reference of the cells. I need to modify this html before it's useful to me.

Comment: Try adding the PublishObjects.item to a variable like this: 


strTargetDivID = ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Item(1).DivID

msgBox strTargetDivID